# Observable.fromAsync not emitting on the proper thread?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have an `Observable` I'm creating using `Observable.fromAsync()` method.  It is waiting for a notification to come back over a `BroadcastReceiver`.  Since that method is going to be called on the Android main thread when I call `AsyncEmitter.onNext()` it doesn't place that call onto the Observable's scheduler and instead tries to run it on the main thread.  Since this Observable chain eventually makes a network call I get this exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1126)
   at okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:105)
   ...
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromAsync$BufferAsyncEmitter.onNext(OnSubscribeFromAsync.java:300)
   at com.nextraq.anders.biz.auth.DefaultActiveSession$1$1.onReceive(DefaultActiveSession.java:90)
   ...
```

That last method is my BroadcastReceiver code calling `emitter.onNext()` which seems to directly call onto the Observable pipeline instead of queuing it.  Actually AsycEmitter.onNext() calls the `drain()` method which triggers this whole sequence.

Here is my Observable code:

```
Observable<String> obs = Observable.fromAsync(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final AsyncEmitter<String> emitter) {
        final LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( context );
        bm.sendBroadcast( new Intent( context, SessionManager.class ).setAction(SessionManager.REFRESH).putExtra(SessionManager.EXTRA_USER_ID, active.getId()) );

        bm.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    switch (intent.getAction()) {
                        case SessionManager.ACTIVE_TOKEN:
                            String token = intent.getStringExtra(SessionManager.EXTRA_TOKEN);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Received broadcast for " + intent.getAction() + " = " + token );
                            emitter.onNext(token);
                            emitter.onCompleted();
                            break;
                        case SessionManager.REFRESH_ERROR:
                            String error = intent.getStringExtra(SessionManager.EXTRA_ERROR);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Received broadcast for " + intent.getAction() + " = " + error );
                            emitter.onError(new RefreshTokenExpiredException(error));
                            break;
                    }
                } finally {
                    bm.unregisterReceiver(this);
                }
            }
        }, intentFilter(SessionManager.ACTIVE_TOKEN,SessionManager.REFRESH_ERROR));
    }
}, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```

Since this is pretty much exactly what the docs state it seems odd to me that AsyncEmitter wouldn't queue the onNext and onComplete requests on the the Observable's scheduler no matter what thread called it.  And if it didn't schedule those calls then why do the docs state it in this manner?

I tried wrapping my `AsyncEmitter` in a `SerializedObserver`, but that didn't help.  Later in my method calls I call these methods:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(new Observer<Trip>() {
   ...
});
```

So what am I supposed to do to make my onNext()/onComplete() calls work over the Schedule.io?

Comment: You are telling the sequence with `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to receive `emitter.onNext(token);` on the main thread. Have you tried making that `observeOn(Schedulers.io())`?

Comment: Well yes and no.  I figured out the issue which is what you are pointing out, but to fix it I had to use a facility provided by our architecture.  Essentially this facility does exactly what you showed.

Comment: @akarnokd Look at this case
`Observable.just(smth)
.flatmap(Observable.fromAsync())
.flatmap(Observable.just())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
`
Why does Observable from second flatmap executes on main thread?

Comment: I guess the fromAsync is triggered on the main thread which then triggers the subscription to just on the main thread as well.